# Is it possible with highcharts to duplicate x aXis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible with highcharts to duplicate x aXis ?

See the picture below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to do this.  But, you can use the xAxis.labels.formatter ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)) to achieve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bf130xrz/

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value + '<br/>' + this.value;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is that possible to change the second line of month with an another array ?

Comment: That at least makes some sense :).  Sure, add an array with the values.  Find the index of this.value in categories, and then reference the added array with that index in the formatter function